# jQuery remove item from sortable list AND update list of item ID's left

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list of sortable images, each image has a unique ID. I also have a text input (on my live site it's hidden, but I've shown it for the purposes of testing), this text input shows the ID's of the images in the order that they are placed in - this list updates whenever the user changes the order of the images.

I have now added a "remove" button to the images, when the user clicks this, the respective image removes. However, what I can't do is update this change (i.e. the image being removed) in my text input.

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("ul.layers-multi-image-list").sortable({
placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
update: function(event, ui) {
  var ordering = $.map($("> li img", this), function(el) {
    return el.id
  }).join(",");
  $('.image_ids').val(ordering);
}
});

$('ul.layers-multi-image-list').disableSelection();

$("ul.layers-multi-image-list").on('click', '.layers-multi-image-remove', function() {
$(this).parent().remove();
});
});
```

How can I make it so that when an image is deleted, the value from the text input is also removed?

Here is a jFiddle to show my working so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/5afo47k1/6/

Comment: I would gather the `id` from the image first. You can then remove the object, and them find and remove the ID Number from your text list.

Comment: Your actual question is: "How do I remove  specific word from a string". Which has been asked and answered a lot. In your case the string is value of input and word is the id of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5afo47k1/7/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("ul.layers-multi-image-list").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var ordering = $.map($("> li img", this), function(el) {
        return el.id
      }).join(",");
      $('.image_ids').val(ordering);
    }
  });

  $('ul.layers-multi-image-list').disableSelection();

  $("ul.layers-multi-image-list").on('click', '.layers-multi-image-remove', function() {
    var imgId = $(this).parent().find("img").attr("id");
    console.log("Removing:", imgId);
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var curList = $('.image_ids').val();
    var st = curList.indexOf(imgId);
    if (st) {
      var end = st + imgId.length;
      console.log("Start: ", st, " End: ", end);
      newList = curList.substring(0, st-1);
      newList += curList.substring(end);
      console.log(newList);
      $('.image_ids').val(newList);
    }
  });
});
```

I first collect the ID from the `img` tag before it's removed:

`var imgId = $(this).parent().find("img").attr("id");`

Then we need to slice it out of the list. Could just re-read the list from the images, but I felt it was faster to manipulate the text:

```
var curList = $('.image_ids').val(); // The current List
var st = curList.indexOf(imgId); // Find if needle is in the list
if (st) { // It is, let's remove it, or do nothing
  var end = st + imgId.length; // 4 numbers in ID
  var newList = curList.substring(0, st-1); // Grab the text before
  newList += curList.substring(end); Ammend the text after
  $('.image_ids').val(newList); // Put it back in the text box
}
```

Hope that helps.

**Update**

Addressed a minor logic bug when removing the first image: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5afo47k1/10/

```
$("ul.layers-multi-image-list").on('click', '.layers-multi-image-remove', function() {
    var imgId = $(this).parent().find("img").attr("id");
    var curList = $('.image_ids').val();
    console.log("Removing:", imgId, " From: ", curList);
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var st = curList.indexOf(imgId);
    if (st >= 0) {
      var end = st + imgId.length;
      console.log("Start: ", st, " End: ", end);
      var newList = "";
      if (st > 0) {
        newList += curList.substring(0, st - 1);
        newList += curList.substring(end);
      } else {
        newList += curList.substring(end + 1);
      }
      console.log(newList);
      $('.image_ids').val(newList);
    }
  });
```

Comment: @SamSkirrow Made a small edit in case IDs change or grow: `imgId.length` instead of `4`. Feel free to upvote and mark it as the answer.

Comment: I also found an issue when you click the first image to remove. Will fix.